# Como isolar o CSS de um componente?

Tags: css, react

Estou usando o react.js (no exemplo o create react app) e cheguei a criar dois componentes, porém não consegui isolar o **.css** de cada componente. O css do tabelaInfo.css acaba sendo aplicado nos outros componentes que possuem as mesmas classes, ou seja ele está sendo **global**. Como posso isolar o **tabelaInfo.css** para ser aplicado somente no componente **TabelaInfo**?

Segundo minhas pesquisas seria algo como o **Scoped CSS** do **Vue.js**.

**TabelaInfo.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import styles from './tabelaInfo.css';

export default class TabelaInfo extends React.Component {
 render() {
 return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Tipo</th>
                    <th>Altura</th>
                    <th>Peso</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bulbasauro</td>
                    <td>Planta</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>100kg</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
 }
}
```

**tabelaInfo.css**

```
table{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr th{
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size:15px;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-align: left;
}
table tr td{
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
```

Comment: O elemento acaba retornando "TabelaInfo" como uma classe de cada elemento?

Answer (score 1):

Uma das soluções propostas pela documentação do React é o uso de [estilos inline](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html).

Em React, **estilos inline** são definidos como um objeto `JavaScript`, sendo que:

- A **chave** é a versão em *camelCase* do nome do estilo (i.e. `backgroundColor`)
- O **valor** é o valor do estilo, normalmente uma `string` (i.e. `'#FFF'`)

Dessa maneira, o seu caso ficaria mais ou menos assim (apenas função `render`):

```
render() {
  const style = {
    width: '100%';
    tableLayout: 'fixed';
    borderCollapse: 'collapse';
    // Demais propriedades
  };

  return (
    <table style={style}>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Tipo</th>
          <th>Altura</th>
          <th>Peso</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Bulbasauro</td>
          <td>Planta</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>100kg</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
```

Você pode ler uma discussão sobre boas práticas de uso do estilo inline em React [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31638988/3551913) (em inglês).

Comment: interessante, cheguei a ver também um pouco de CSS Modules, porém não consegui chegar a algo parecido com scoped css do vue.js